# How to create a Firefox theme (addon?) from a simple stylesheet?

Tags: firefox-addon

I have created a theme for Firefox that involve a simple stylesheet. I am currently using Stylish extension for this but would like to share my theme as an Firefox addon (since Theme are simple image).
I didn't quickly find anything about that in search engine and only find an outdated ressource on MDN.

Any tip to make share this CSS as an addon? (bonus: automate release from a git repo)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a simple stylesheet as you described, then you would have to attach the stylesheet to the nsIDOMWindow. Example code with addon-sdk

```
const { attachTo, detachFrom } = require("sdk/content/mod");
const { Style } = require("sdk/stylesheet/style");
const { getMostRecentWindow } = require("sdk/window/utils");
const { browserWindows } = require("sdk/windows");
const { viewFor } = require("sdk/view/core");
const style = Style({
  uri: "./index.css" // path to file
});

attachTo(style, getMostRecentWindow());


browserWindows.on("open", function(window) {
  attachTo(style,viewFor(window));
});

require("sdk/system/unload").when(function() {
  for (let window of browserWindows)
    detachFrom(style, viewFor(window));
});
```

**EDIT**:
To start using addon-sdk you must have jpm. [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/jpm#Installation) it is described how to install it. Once you installed it, you should create a directory that will contain your extension. Then open a terminal/console and type jpm init. Fill the prompted fields according to your needs. You can also check out [these](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tools/package_json) additional options available in the package.json (it's in the root of your directory with the extension) and use them aswell.

The next step is to paste my code in the index.js (you can paste the code somewhere else but then you have to import that file using require). Create a directory "data" in the extension directory and create a file with stylesheet there. Then replace "index.css" here

```
uri: "./index.css"
```

with your file name.

Once you are done, type jpm xpi in your terminal/console and your extension is ready to install! Good luck

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Any more detail about addon-sdk? I didn't find any simple tutorial to create a addon from scratch.

Comment: I've just updated my answer. Once you are done, the ".xpi" file will be generated and you will be able to install your extension (but you have to turn off the cert checking - you can do it in about:config page via xpinstall.signatures.required preference - make it false)

Comment: Thanks for this. This helps a lot. I successfully created my theme :) That said I have a last extra question: is there a simple way to edit my add-on during the runtime without regenerating the plugin? I tried to use "Browser Toolbox" from the Tools menu but I didn't find my stylesheet with others (note that I found some of a different plugin (Beyond Australis) that probably use a different way to insert CSS https://github.com/Quicksaver/The-Fox--Only-Better). Any tips to easily edit the CSS on the installed add-on?

Comment: I found "jpm run --debug" after digging a little, but I am not able to see my CSS in the Add-on Debugger. Any tip?

Comment: The Beyond Australis uses a different, more complicated way, but it has to, as it does some extra stuff with xul. 
You won't be able edit your index.css once the extension is loaded.
There are 3 ways though to edit the theme.
First: Install extension each time (jpm --watchpost and [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/pl/firefox/addon/autoinstaller/?src=ss)) may help you. 
Second: Create a page where you could paste the new code and make changes as you edit theme there. (then you could copy and paste the new code to the current and recreate the extension).
Third: Keep theme in the profile dir.

Comment: @MoOx I'll post the description about the second way in a couple of minutes.

Comment: @MoOx I've just created a repo containg an example addon https://bitbucket.org/Knut_/stack_addon/src

Once you install extension or run your browser a new tab will be open called "Theme edit" and you can paste your code there (in textarea), once you are done, click outside that textarea and the changes will be visible. NOTE: it's not a permanent change - this means it will persist as long as you don't close your browser or disable your extension.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.